OpenCV cpp with VS Code on Mac M3
I've just moved to Mac and I'm setting up the environment. However, I have a big problem with the cpp libraries in VS Code that I cannot solve...
I've installed opencv with brew, and it finished in opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/include/opencv4/opencv2, so in this folder I have opencv.hpp
In VS Code I setup my c_cpp_properties.json in this way:
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/include/opencv4"
            
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-arm64",
        "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    }
],
"version": 4

}
and the tasks.json like this
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/include/opencv4"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"

}
The problem is that when I write in my code #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" I get this error directly in the editor and during the building 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found gcc [Ln 2, Col 10].
I tried to add / /** /* at the end of the path but nothing changes, while if I import doing other paths I get extra errors saying that the path doesn't exist.
Is someone able to help me?

"-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/include/opencv4" sets the link folder but does not link to anything. Also why do you want to link to compiled binaries in an include folder? To set the include path its capital I not capital L

You may want to use CMake for this and the CMake tools extension. Once you start using external libraries like opencv its usually better to go with a proper build system.

Yes, the error was the -I instead of -L. And you are right, I should move to CMake and better structure the project. Thank you for the help
